# A cohomology associated with a codimension one foliation(2)

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, cohomology, foliations

What is  an example  of  a codimension one foliation of  a  manifold for which [this cohomology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195254/a-cohomology-associated-with-a-codimension-one-foliation) is  finite  dimension for  all dimension $*$?

Moreover what is the description of this cohomology for the Reeb foliation of $S^{3}$?

Comment: $H^1$ is never finite dimensional: it contains at least $\Omega^0\wedge\alpha$.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev  Thank you.  So what about if  we restrict ourselves to even cohomology?